# 404 Error after success installing magento 2.4.2-sp1 using Windows 10 + composer --XAMP

Tags: php-7, apache2, mysql8

**My current Environment is**
>Server version: Apache/2.4.48 (Win64)
>Apache Lounge VS16 Server built:   May 18 2021 10:45:56

> PHP 7.4.20RC1 (cli)
>  (built: May 19 2021 17:12:38)
>  ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
> Copyright (c) The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

> Node
> v14.17.0

**I have received a successful install after running:**

> php -d memory_limit=-1 magento setup:install --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/magento/" --db-host="127.0.0.1" --db-name="magento" --db-user="root" --db-password="1691" --admin-firstname="donald" --admin-lastname="duck" --admin-email="admin@admin.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --language="en_US" --currency="AUD" --timezone="Australia/Adelaide" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin"

**I am now back to my prompt**

> [SUCCESS]: Magento installation complete.
> [SUCCESS]: Magento Admin URI: /admin
> Nothing to import.
> PS C:\apache24\htdocs\magento\bin>

**I have a Response from ElasticSearch**
*http://localhost:9200/*

> {
> "name" : "DESKTOP-I3R9BC8",
> "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
> "cluster_uuid" : "0HIm1CYpTiKi6OUfehm4eQ",
> "version" : {
> "number" : "7.13.1",
> "build_flavor" : "default",
> "build_type" : "zip",
> "build_hash" : "9a7758028e4ea59bcab41c12004603c5a7dd84a9",
> "build_date" : "2021-05-28T17:40:59.346932922Z",
> "build_snapshot" : false,
> "lucene_version" : "8.8.2",
> "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
> "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
> },
> "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
> }

*http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty*

> {
> "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
> "status" : "yellow",
> "timed_out" : false,
> "number_of_nodes" : 1,
> "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
> "active_primary_shards" : 1,
> "active_shards" : 1,
> "relocating_shards" : 0,
> "initializing_shards" : 0,
> "unassigned_shards" : 1,
> "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
> "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
> "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
> "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
> "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 50.0
> }

**httpd.conf file settings**

> Define SRVROOT "c:/Apache24"
> ServerRoot "${SRVROOT}"
> Listen 80
> LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
> LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
> LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
> LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
> LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
> LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
> LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
> LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
> LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
> LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
> LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
> LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
> LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
> LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
> LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
> LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
> LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
> LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
> LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
> LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
> LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
> LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
>
> User daemon
> Group daemon
>
> ServerAdmin admin@example.com
> ServerName localhost
>
> AllowOverride All
> Require all denied
>
> DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
> <Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
> AllowOverride All
> Require all granted
>
>
> DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
>
> <Files ".ht*">
> Require all denied
>
> ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
> LogLevel warn
>
> LogFormat "%h %l %u %t "%r" %>s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i"" combined
> LogFormat "%h %l %u %t "%r" %>s %b" common
>
> LogFormat "%h %l %u %t "%r" %>s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i" %I %O" combinedio
>
> CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
>
>
> ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin/"
>
> <Directory "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin">
> AllowOverride None
> Options None
> Require all granted
>
>
> RequestHeader unset Proxy early
>
>
> TypesConfig conf/mime.types
> AddType application/x-compress .Z
> AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
>
>
> Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
>
>
> SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
> SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
>
> PHPIniDir "C:/PHP-742"
> AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
> LoadModule php7_module "C:/PHP-742/php7apache2_4.dll"

**.htaccess file is present at root of magento folder**

> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
> RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]
> DirectoryIndex index.php

**Response from http://localhost/magento/**

> Not Found
> The requested URL was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

Go to apache settings and make sure that the document root is pointing to the `<magento_root>/pub` folder.

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html#1-edit-your-server-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Please install virtual host for the version 2.4.2 you are using.
You can refer to how to create a virtual host here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart